# Calculating a custom total for a column on iPad mini and Numbers

Tags: ios, ipad, numbers

How do I make a formula to total (sum) a column using Numbers on iOS, but exclude negative numbers?  (Only sum positive numbers)

Example:

```
+-------+
| LIST  |
+-------+
|      1|
|      2|
|      3|
|      0|
|     -1|
|     -2|
|     -3|
+-------+
|Total 6|
+-------+
```

Basically, how can I calculate a total but ignoring negative numbers in the column?

Comment: Are you looking for a Sum total (0 wouldn’t matter anyway) or an Average total or what exactly? Would love to help if you could be a bit more precise. Cheers

Comment: Just wanting a total but ignoring negative numbers in the column.

Answer (score 1):

Summing a column with conditions can be done with the `SUMIF()` or `SUMIFS` functions.

> The SUMIF function is a worksheet function that adds all numbers in a range of cells based on one criteria (for example, is equal to 2000). To add numbers in a range based on multiple criteria, try the SUMIFS function.

For example:

`=SUMIFS(A2:A10, A2:A10, “>0”)`

Looks at all values greater than 0 and totals them up.

[image: SUMIFS Function]

---

#### To use formulas and functions in Numbers for iOS:

- Select the cell in which you wish to have the calculation.  (In the attached example, for instance, cell `A11`)
- Type the equals sign character <kbd>=</kbd> or select circled equals sign icon.
- Start typing the name of the function you wish to use, or tap the ***f<sub>x</sub>*** at the top left of the virtual keyboard to see a list of functions to choose from.

For more detailed information on how to use formulas and functions in Numbers for iOS, please see the [official documentation here from Apple.](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/7.3/#/ffaef5aeec8)

[image: Enter a function in Numbers for iOS]

[image: Functions list]

Comment: Thanks bjbk, but is SUMIFS available on iPad Numbers? I don't see it offered to me when I press the function button.

Comment: The screenshot attached is from iPad. In the cell first type an equal sign. Then type the function name. All functions are available. I’ll add more details to the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks bjbk. Thanks for the example shots. They are what pointed me to 'categories' which was what I needed. I obviously don't know how to navigate my way around Numbers. Thanks again. I may be back with m next problem soon.

Comment: Glad it helped. If that answered your question please mark answered for the benefit of others.

Comment: Sorry bkbk but I adjust looking how to do that but can't see it.

Comment: You may want to do some research on how to use spreadsheets in general. Type in the example I sent on a blank sheet to get the idea. Then you should be able to apply that to your original data. Other than that, some tutorials on using Numbers should help you. Cheers!

Comment: Great answer, definitely accepted if I could see a button to do that.

Comment: Depending on how you access the site, the accept answer button is under the voting number. Where the up arrow, 0, down arrow are to the left of the answer.